# Matching a word, but not in a comment

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to match a word, but not in cases where it is preceded by a comment (`/*` not followed by `*/`).  I've been trying to use negative lookahead assertions to accomplish this with no luck so far.  Is this going to be possible with negative lookahead or negative lookbehind assertions, or is this a futile effort?

Comment: Where are your efforts?  Can you include what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just assuming you are writing Perl script, trying to analyze C code.

It might be some single and elegant regex doing it, but then you have to read the whole file and make it a single string. I remember having problems while tried to run Perl regex on strings containing multiple lines (`\n` characters), but maybe it's just me.

Anyway, I would suggest you to process it line by line, taking care of 3 cases:

1. Single line comment: `/* my comment */`
2. Comment beginning on the current line: `/* my comment starts here`
3. Comment ending on the current line:  `my comment ends here */`

Remove the comment from the text being analyzed, and search for your word in the rest. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $word = shift;
my $line_no = 0;
my $whole_line = "";

my $in_comment = 0;

sub word_detection
{
    while ($_ =~ /\b($word)\b/g)
    {
        print "'$1' found on line $line_no: $whole_line\n";
    }
}

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    $whole_line = $_;
    $line_no ++;

    $_ =~ s/\/\*.*?\*\///;

    if ($_ =~ /\/\*/)
    {
        my @split = (split /\/\*/,  $_);
        $_ = $split[0];
        $in_comment = 1;
        word_detection $_;
    }
    elsif ($_ =~ /\*\//)
    {
        my @split = (split /\*\//,  $_);
        $_ = $split[1];
        $in_comment = 0;
        word_detection $_;
    }
    elsif (not $in_comment)
    {
        word_detection $_;
    }
}
```

Run this script with your word as first argument ('int' in the example below) and then your file name. It should do the job:

```
$ match-word int test.cc
'int' found on line 11: int /* comment on one line */ x = 10;
'int' found on line 13: int y; /* and this is
'int' found on line 15:     comment */ int z;
'int' found on line 17: int main(int argc, char* argv[])
'int' found on line 17: int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: `/*` and `*/` can also occur inside a string literal or a single line comment.